# How can I get parents' parents' child's value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a student who is studying Python alone these days.
Below is part of my HTML page's JavaScript code.

```
let temp_html_0 = `<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top"
         src="${image}"
         alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a target="_blank" href="${url}" class="card-title">${title}</a>
        <p class="reason-comment">REASON : ${comment}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-result">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="confirm()">Confirm</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reject()">Reject</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
`
```

javascript function :

```
function confirm(){
    alert('confirmed')
    let test = $(this).parent().parent().find(".card-img-top").attr("src");
    alert(test)
    window.location.reload()
}
```

What I want to do is:

When user clicks btn-success button,
call confirm() function,
and get img src (`${image}` in my code)
to call AJAX.

I tried code above but it didn't work.
How can I get img src value?

Comment: I am not using each elements' id because temp_html_0 will be repeated. thank you!

Comment: Where and how are you calling `$(this).parent().parent().find(".card-img-top").attr("src")`? I assume it's in the `confirm()` function but we probably need the code for it. Right now there is no [mcve] which makes it hard to guess what's wrong .

Comment: Hi, just pass `this` inside your function i.e :`onclick="confirm(this)"` and then simply use `function confirm(el) {let test = $(el).parent().parent().find(".card-img-top").attr("src")}`

Comment: Swati's answer works well!!! Thank you so much my sweet teacher!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I see that temp_html_0 will be repeated, then why not just use a subclass with a unique identifier like the iteration index for example and add it to your image class as the following

`<img class="card-img-top top-img-{index}">`

And then you can pass that index to your function and get that element by using your logic.

Comment: "*then why not just use a subclass with a unique identifier like the iteration index for example*" because it's a bad idea. It's a crutch at best an unneeded most of the time with the existence of `data-*` attributes.

Comment: Yes thank you for the information, I'll consider this next time

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the button reference in HTML event binding `confirm(this)` `reject(this)`, then you may access the parent and image src in both of the methods as shown in be below snippet.

```js
function confirm(btn) {
  var $btn = $(btn);
  var imgSrc = $btn.closest('.card').find('.card-img-top').attr('src');
  console.log(`confirmed - ${imgSrc}`);
}

function reject(btn) {
  var $btn = $(btn);
  var imgSrc = $btn.closest('.card').find('.card-img-top').attr('src');
  console.log(`rejected - ${imgSrc}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="${image}" alt=" Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a target="_blank" href="${url}" class="card-title">${title}</a>
        <p class="reason-comment">REASON : ${comment}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-result">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="confirm(this)">Confirm</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reject(this)">Reject</button>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The core of the problem is that you use the `onclick` attribute. The value of it is `confirm()`, so when activated it will call the function *but not set the context in any way*. So `this` will be `window` (if you're not in [strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it/)).

A quick fix would be to modify the function definition to `function confirm(el){`  and the HTML to `onclick="confirm(this)"` in order to have access to the element that's clicked as a parameter. This leads to this code:

```js
function confirm(el){
    console.log('confirmed')
    let test = $(el).parent().parent().find(".card-img-top").attr("src");
    console.log(test)
    //window.location.reload()
}

//////////////////////////////

const image = "foo";
const url = "bar";
const title = "baz";
const comment = "quux";

let temp_html_0 = `<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top"
         src="${image}"
         alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a target="_blank" href="${url}" class="card-title">${title}</a>
        <p class="reason-comment">REASON : ${comment}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-result">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="confirm(this)">Confirm</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reject()">Reject</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
`

$("#main").append(temp_html_0);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

However, a better technique is to use [event binding on dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) using [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation). It will execute the function with the correct context and further allows you to still have a single event handler but you do not mix the HTML with logic that JavaScript would use.:

```js
function confirm(){
    console.log('confirmed')
    let test = $(this).parent().parent().find(".card-img-top").attr("src");
    console.log(test)
    //window.location.reload()
}

$("#main") // --> common ancestor for all your dynamic elements
  .on("click", ".btn-success", confirm);
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^ --> event handler to execute
//              ↳ element to monitor for clicks

function reject(){
    console.log('rejected');
}

$("#main").on("click", ".btn-danger", reject);


//////////////////////////////

const image = "foo";
const url = "bar";
const title = "baz";
const comment = "quux";

let temp_html_0 = `<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top"
         src="${image}"
         alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a target="_blank" href="${url}" class="card-title">${title}</a>
        <p class="reason-comment">REASON : ${comment}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-result">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Reject</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
`

$("#main").append(temp_html_0);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly pass image src as parameter into confirm function call like this:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onnclick="confirm(${image})">Confirm</button>`

and you can get this parameter value inside confirm function.